# Adding multiple A records - Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Here !FindInMap [NetworkParam, default, R53ZoneName]- Get the CN for the domain. (say example.com)

now i need to populate Route53 A records Name as

```
stat.example.com
log.example.com
it.example.com
web.example.com
```

But my cloudformation failed with this join function. I know i can add as indexes , prob is i don't want to add 4 indexes under Name. Select [0,SubDomains]

```
SubDomains:
    Default: "'stat', 'log', 'it', 'web'"
    Type: String
    Description: subdomains

DnsRecordA:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
    Properties:
        AliasTarget:
        HostedZoneId: !GetAtt ApplicationLoadBalancer.CanonicalHostedZoneID
        DNSName: !GetAtt ApplicationLoadBalancer.DNSName
        EvaluateTargetHealth: false
        HostedZoneId: !FindInMap [NetworkParameters, default, R53ZoneId]
        Name: !Join ["".,[!Ref SubDomains,".",!FindInMap [NetworkParam, default, R53ZoneName], ],]
            Type: A
```

it says E0000 did not find expected ',' or ']' . from cfn-lint, Template format error: YAML not well-formed. (line 333, column 14) (from cloudformation)

```
     Name: 
        !Join [
           "".,
           [
              !Ref SubDomains,
              ".dev.",
              !FindInMap [NetworkParam, default, R53ZoneName],
           ],
        ]
     Type: A
```

Comment: " cloudformation failed" - is not specific. What **exactly** happened? Any errors?

Comment: it sayd E0000 did not find expected ',' or ']' .

Comment: What you're trying to achieve? ```Subdomains``` isn't a list in your code, you can't go through it's indexes. Can you share the Mapping you're trying to read to form a value for the Name property?

Comment: !FindInMap [NetworkParam, default, R53ZoneName], returns the CN name, lets say example.com, SubDomains got list of strings -  "'stat', 'log', 'it', 'web'", now need to add 4 A Records. stat.dev.example.com, log.dev.example.com etc.